# Fatal database error on insert() with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting this error and I don't know what to do:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>    Severity: Notice
>    Message: Undefined property: Welcome::$db
>    Filename: core/Model.php
>    Line Number: 52
>    Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\application\models\account_model.php on line 38

**Controller:**

```
public function register()//function register in the controller
{
        $this->load->model('account_model');
        $this->account_model->create_account(); 
}
```

**Model:**

```
function create_account()//function insert.
{
    $insertdata = array('id' =>'',
        'firstname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'password' => $this->input->post('pass'),
        'role' => '1',
        'status' => 'Active');

    $insert = $this->db->insert('account', $insertdata);
    return $insert; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the database library into your autoload configuration file, have you already done that?

It is located in ../application/config/autoload.php, search for:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

and add the database library like this:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Comment: Big help Konstantin. However after i change it, another error appeared. Your application/config/database.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.

Comment: Sorry my bad. this is the error. --- Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 125

Answer (score 0):

In `config/autoload.php`, load `database` library

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Comment: I got this error . Your application/config/database.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.

Comment: Sorry my bad. this is the error. --- Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings. Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\system\database\DB_driver.php Line Number: 125

Comment: Check your `database.php` and provide your db details

Comment: @adulla thanks for the big help. I already figured out what's the problem. Till next time! have a good day.

Comment: @Glenn ok ok. Enjoy coding :)